# Testlink Jenkins result integration not working

Tags: selenium, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, testlink

I want to sync automation result from jenkins to testlink. I tried with Testlink -jenking plugin and testlink-api-client but not worked getting error.

Pre-setup :
$tlCfg-> api-> enabled
$tlCfg-> exec_cfg-> enable_test_automation
From Testlink UI enable automation for the project. 
Test code : 
TestLinkAPIClient testlinkAPIClient = new TestLinkAPIClient(APIKEY, "http://localhost/testlink/lib/api/xmlrpc/v1/xmlrpc.php");

testlinkAPIClient.reportTestCaseResult(Project, TestPlan, TEST_CASE, Build, notes/comments, teststatus);
output : 
"testlink.api.java.client.TestLinkAPIException: The call to the xml-rpc client failed.". 
References used :satishjohn.wordpress.com
2. softwaretestinghelp.com
and other stackoverflow threads.

I browsed and try out defined steps from some of the blogs but still facing same issue?. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue or other approach on sync result with testlink ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should follow the documentation(1) written by kino who wrote the plugin.We recently managed to sync automation results from Jenkins to Testlink by following above doc.Our auto tests were written based on testng framework, Hence we used "testng-results.xml" and TestNg method name based result seeking strategy.

We didn't come across an issue as you mentioned. From (2) and (3) you can get the plugin source .My advice is to debug the code after enabling the debug on Jenkins hosted tomcat server. So you can find the actual cause of the issue by yourself.
Reference:

(1) https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/download/attachments/753702/jenkins.pdf
(2) https://github.com/jenkinsci/testlink-plugin 
(3) https://github.com/kinow/testlink-java-api`enter code here`

Comment: Thanks for Reply. For now, we wrote REST API in TESTLink which fetches the test cases and sync the result from selenium. (this sync function we wrote @afterMethod in our framework ). Though this approach hit the script execution performance slightly.But was working fine.  I will check the above links.

Comment: Yes, Its possible to update TestLink directly from code as you have mentioned. Apart from Performance degrade It will make you tightly bind to TestLink, inn case you need use another testcase management system.

Answer (score 0):

You can run wireshark and filter on port "tcp port http" to see exact error you get from the server. When it was not working for us we were getting 200 OK with text "XML-RPC server accepts POST requests only."
You can also check /var/log/apache2/error.log for testlink errors.

We fixed the issue by setting following config in config.inc.php and restarting apache.

```
$tlCfg->api->enabled = TRUE;
$tlCfg->exec_cfg->enable_test_automation = ENABLED;
```

Comment: Instead of using Wireshark or any other n/w tapping tools ,we can use browser console to get all responses. We tried already to capture req and responce  with browser console,using defined config but still no luck. So we wrote REST service in Testlink, which suited much better for our requirements. Thanks for response.